# Angularjs e2e test with testacular disconnects all browsers

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Iam trying to get working e2e test on my AngularJs project using testacular. I launch a web server based on node.js successfully and I can see how the file are sended when a url is loaded, even I can see the sight result on my browsers but Testacular tests do not work. I get this error:

```
[2013-04-04 00:31:00.499] [WARN] config - "/" is proxied, you should probably change urlRoot to avoid conflicts
INFO [testacular]: Testacular server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
INFO [Chrome 26.0 (Mac)]: Connected on socket id EN7sZuseiLuwlddbBkqn
INFO [Firefox 13.0 (Mac)]: Connected on socket id lBTUcn8b75p5O_cPBkqo
Chrome 26.0 (Mac): Executed 0 of 3
Chrome 26.0 (Mac): Executed 0 of 3 DISCONNECTED (0.413 secs / 0 secs)
Firefox 13.0 (Mac): Executed 0 of 3 DISCONNECTED (0.31 secs / 0 secs)
WARN [Chrome 26.0 (Mac)]: Disconnected
```

This is my testacular config file:

```
basePath = '../';

files = [
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  'test/e2e/**/*.js'
];

autoWatch = true;
browsers = ['Chrome', 'Firefox'];
singleRun = false;

proxies = {
  '/': 'http://localhost:8000/'
};

junitReporter = {
  outputFile: 'test_out/e2e.xml',
  suite: 'e2e'
};
```

Any idea about what I am doing worng?

Comment: I have updated my system and now i am using karma-runner instead of testacular but I still have the same result

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. I am using index.html asynch flavor and it turns out that you also need to put `ng-app` in the `document.body`.

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);

document.body.className = document.body.className + ' ng-app';
```

Reference: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/422